# can we use smarty with zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, smarty

Any body know can we use smarty with zend framework. If yes what is the advantage of using like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out

http://devzone.zend.com/article/120

and

http://kpumuk.info/php/zend-framework-using-smarty-as-template-engine/

Answer (score 3):

You can, it's not much work.
But i can tell you i switched from Smarty to Zend_View a long time ago, those view-helpers are a real elegant way working with the zend framework components and wrapping them for smarty is a really non-trivial task, as smarty templates yet not know arrays, and you will need them often: URL-View-Helper and many more.

Skip Smarty it's the best choice when working with the Zend_Framework ;)

Answer (score 0):

The only advantage i see to use Smarty is for a Smarty Experienced team. The idea is great, but php is already a template language (besides others things). I like the PHPTemplate engine of Drupal.